# I want to extract into a table just clients that have the same developer id

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, entity-framework

I encountered a problem where i have a table with all my developers. [image] when i try to click the first button to show customers that are related to that specific developer is appearing my entire list of clients [image]
My question is how i make to appear just the clients for one specific developer.

Here is my code for show-Client:

```
export class ShowClientComponent implements OnInit {
    
      clientList$!: Observable<any[]>;
      developerList$! : Observable<any[]>;
    
      constructor(private clientService: ClientApiService,
        private developerService : DeveloperApiService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.clientList$ = this.clientService.getClientList();
        this.developerList$ = this.developerService.getDeveloperList();
      }
```

Client Service:

```
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
          getClientList():Observable<any[]>{
              return this.http.get<any>(this.clientApiUrl + '');
      }
```

Comment: Please post the source code text directly instead of a screenshot

Comment: See also (How do I ask a good question)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Hi, i tried to resolve.

Comment: I will read this right now. Thanks!